# Will the Cisco AIR-LAP1262N access point support 802.11ac?

Tags: wireless-networking

I know that .11ac is still only a draft spec and it's impossible to answer with 100% certainty, but does anyone know if the Cisco AP 1262 wap will be able to support it?

Comment: I would check the product specifications for the product. Every time of 802.11 revision the product supports would be listed there.  The product only supports 802.11n its not possible for it to support 802.11ac

Answer (score 2):

802.11ac will most likely require some radio hardware changes so it's a good bet that if it doesn't support it now (which it doesn't) it will not in the future. Also, Cisco is big into selling more hardware, so it is unlikely that they would allow an upgrade to 802.11ac with just a code upgrade.

[1260 Data Sheet](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/wireless/ps5678/ps10980/data_sheet_c78-593663.html)